# Kernel Died When Using EasyOCR

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-import

I followed all necessary instructions. I installed PyTorch for Windows. I am using Python version 3.9.7. However, I tried all versions of easyocr, but every time I import it, the kernel died.
When I uninstall this library, the kernel is working again.

I don't get any error in easyocr installation.
Can anyone help who knows the source of this problem?

[Necessary Explanations for PyTorch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPDgz.png)

[Kernel Died When import easyOCR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUb0G.png)

[Kernel Died](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgaZw.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: same error to me. Some solution?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error, but I was able to resolve it by rolling back to the previous version of **Python 3.7.0**. Now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
os.environ['KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK']='True'
```

Comment: Hi @freshlj, Usually a code block with just a "try this" is not a very good answer. It helps the community much more if you could tell us why we should try this code and why it would/might help the op. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Then Kernal was keep failing then I upgraded Numpy; using command

pip install -U numpy --user

Now, it works for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me :

import os
os.environ['KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK']='True'

https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2784#issuecomment-1195852342

Comment: This answer was already provided a year and a half ago. Please don't repeat answers.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the kernel was getting dead on the instruction when I gave the image as input to the easyocr reader. Simply resizing the image to a smaller size worked in my case.